# How can I use with the Daynamic sql for update table in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new in oracle .I create a table with columns and insert data into table
my code is :

```
create table Tbl_Job_Desc 
(
id int,
name varchar2(50),
family varchar2(50),
jobname varchar2(50)
)


INSERT INTO Tbl_Job_Desc (id,name,family,jobname )VALUES (1,'negar','GHANBARIAN','PROGRAMMER');
INSERT INTO Tbl_Job_Desc (id,name,family,jobname )VALUES (2,'ZAHRA','GHANBARIAN','STUDENT');
INSERT INTO Tbl_Job_Desc (id,name,family,jobname )VALUES (3,'SHIRIN','SAEEDI','NURSE');
INSERT INTO Tbl_Job_Desc (id,name,family,jobname )VALUES (4,'FATEME','GHASEMI','TEACHER');
INSERT INTO Tbl_Job_Desc (id,name,family,jobname )VALUES (5,'mohammad','AZADI','PROGRAMMER');
```

I want Write a procedure that takes an input from the user and produces an update statement as follows.
update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname='newjob'
I write this procedure but I get error ,please take  a look my procedure and help me  .
my procedure is :

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Ds_sampleTest (
                                      newjob  IN VARCHAR2
                                     
                                       )
IS
  newjob VARCHAR2(200);
  query  VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN

    query := 'update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname='||newjob' ;
    
    dbms_output.Put_line(query);

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
END;


-- Run the Procedure
CL scr
SET serveroutput ON
BEGIN
    Ds_sample( 'doctor');

    COMMIT;
END;
```

I want Write a procedure that takes an input from the user and produces an update statement as follows.
update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname='newjob'
my error is : PLS-00103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use dynamic SQL if you do not need to:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Ds_sampleTest (
  newjob IN Tbl_Job_Desc.Jobname%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  update Tbl_Job_Desc
  set Jobname = newjob;
END;
/
```

(And do not create local variables that shadow the procedure's parameters.)

Then:

```sql
CL scr
SET serveroutput ON

BEGIN
    Ds_sampleTest( 'doctor');
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

---

If you must use dynamic SQL (you do not need to so you should not) then use bind variables rather than string concatenation when you are passing values:

```sql
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Ds_sampleTest (
  newjob IN Tbl_Job_Desc.Jobname%TYPE
)
IS
  query VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  query := 'update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname = :1';
  dbms_output.Put_line(query);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query USING newjob;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uVdgsAjK)

Comment: thank you a lot , but I edited my question , ID for each one if different and I want for each id I want I would be change this jobname ,please help me

Comment: @faziii1990 Add a second parameter to the procedure for the `id` and then add a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` statement that filters on the `id` parameter that you pass to the procedure.

Comment: @MTO thank you for helping me but I get error when I write this line of code :query := 'update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname = :newjob' where newid := id; I get error : PLS-00103 ,please help me  .

Comment: @faziii1990 `query := 'update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname = :newjob where :newid = id';` and then pass both parameters in the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. (But you really should not be using dynamic SQL as you do not need it.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the error message you are getting to your question would be helpful.

If there are no errors posting your code, then I think your error is related to this part of your code:

```sql
query := 'update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname='||newjob' ;
```

In this case, if you want to add quotes to the text, you need to double quote your quotes in the text, the correct code in your example is:

```sql
query := 'update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname='''||newjob||'''' ;
```

This will save query as:

```
update Tbl_Job_Desc set Jobname='your_newjob'
```

So, whenever you want to add quotes to your text, you need to make them double.
If you want a quote in the middle of your text, you write:

```
my_text := 'My text with '' quote'
```

If you want a quote at the beginning or end of your text, you put a double quote, and then the quote to begin or end your text:

```
my_text := '''There''s a quote at the beginning'
```

If you want to concatenate a quote to a text, then you need to put the normal quotes at the beginning and end of the text and the double quote, which makes for four consecutive quotes:

```
my_text := '''' || 'I''m concatenating a quote at the beginning'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your replying But I write your statement but again I get error :PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted .

Comment: I want Write a procedure that takes an input from the user and produces an update statement as follows.

Comment: Creating SQL queries using string concatenation is bad practice as it introduces SQL injection vulnerabilities and will cause errors when the input contains a single quote. (Especially if you are using unsanitised user input.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem is you are getting this error message when you try to compile your procedure:

```
Errors: PROCEDURE DS_SAMPLETEST
Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Line/Col: 1/1 PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted
```

The error says that you have declared **newjob** as an IN argument of your procedure but you are at the same time declaring a variable in your procedure with the same name:

```
newjob VARCHAR2(200);
```

That it is not allowed, you can delete this line in the declaration, you have declared **newjob** as IN parameter, or if for some other reason you need to have another variable with the same value as the IN parameter, you use another name, something like this:

```
v_newjob VARCHAR2(200) := newjob;
```